# Accessing SQL connection variables in all classes?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I haven't touched PHP in a couple months and don't have access to any of my previous projects for reference. Essentially, I have my file `lib.php` which instantiates all objects, creates all vars/functions that will be accessed throughout most of the application. This file, `lib.php` is then called into the header.php file, via`require_once`. Within lib, I have a function which creates the MySQL PDO connection

```
try {
    $server = array(
            'server' => 'localhost:3306',
            'database' => 'to_do_list',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            );
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server['server'].';dbname='.$server['database'].'',$server['user'],$server['password']);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error Could not connect to database";
    exit;
}
```

I want the variables within here, such as `$link` to be accessible in all class files which are instantiated within lib.php. How would I go about doing this in the most efficient way?

```
<?php
// Session Start
session_start();

// Link Database
// Link var created here I want to be accessible in any classes instantiated below
try {
    $server = array(
            'server' => 'localhost:3306',
            'database' => 'to_do_list',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            );
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server['server'].';dbname='.$server['database'].'',$server['user'],$server['password']);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error Could not connect to database";
    exit;
}

// Functions
// Action GET/POST/SET
function getAction()
{
    if(isset($_POST['action']))
    {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
    } else if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
    } else {
        echo "GET/SET/POST action master failed";
    }
    return $action;
}

// Input GET/POST/SET
function inputReturn($inputName) {
    if(isset($_POST[$inputName])) {
        $inputVal = $_POST[$inputName];
    } else if (isset($_GET[$inputName])) {
        $inputVal = $_GET[$inputName];
    } else {
        $inputVal = "";
        echo "GET/SET/POST input master failed";
    }
    return $inputVal;
}

// Require classes
require_once("user.php");

// Instantiate classes
$instUser = new user;

?>
```

Comment: The website will load faster if each page only instantiates the things it needs rather than having all pages instantiate all the things.

Comment: @CptMiser thanks, I'll make those changes. Will this also allow me to gain access to the $link variable if I continue to include lib.php in the header?

Comment: best practice is to pass the vars you need to the object on creation. Easiest is to access them inside the class via global. But that's not recommended for various reasons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and